# Object instantiates on top of the previous object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, instantiation

I've written a script where a level is supposed to be instantiated when my character hits a specific location. It works perfectly the first time it's meant to instantiate. But on the second time, it instantiates the level directly on top of the previous level. Here's a video of whats happening: https://vimeo.com/283706809 And here's the code (It isn't all of the code, only the code relevant to this question):

```
if (collision.tag == "Score2")
{
    scoreText.text = (++score).ToString();
    Destroy(collision.gameObject);
    int randomNumber = Random.Range(0, 2);
    if (randomNumber == 0)
        Instantiate(course[0], new Vector2(-0.39f, -2f + transform.position.z), transform.rotation);
    else
        Instantiate(course[1], new Vector2(-0.39f, -2f + transform.position.z), transform.rotation);
    return;
```

Comment: Did you mean to put -2f + transform.position.y in the new Vector2?

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a 2D game, you shouldn't really be using the 'z' of the Vector3 class. I think you might've meant to put `new Vector2 (-0.39f, -2f + transform.position.y)` instead of `new Vector2(-0.39f, -2f + transform.position.z)`.

Comment: But wouldn't that mean you're using the Z vector? you've replaced Z with -2f, and left out Y